# How to remove a menu path defined in hook_menu from naviagtion

Tags: routes

I've added two paths for use my my module (for OAuth authentication), but I don't want them to appear as links in menus. I tried defining their 'type' as `MENU_CALLBACK` but they still appear.

Is there a better way to define paths which aren't necessarily pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add `type` to the array in `hook_menu`, it will not be displayed as a menu, but still will be accessible (by code)

```
$items['menu/%/link1'] = array(
   'title' => 'Link1',
// 'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
   'page callback' => 'link1()',
   'page arguments' => array(1),
   'access callback' => TRUE, //'has_access',
);
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem was, you have to assign a 'title', which seems counter intuitive. If the 'title' element is omitted a blank entry is placed in the menu.